# Qt reading ini file doesn't return the value

Tags: qt

Using notepad, I've created the following config.ini file and placed it the same folder as the application:

```
 [Test]
 TestVal=5
```

In Qt5, when I try to read the value (5), it always returns with the default (8) instead of the value from the file:

```
 QSettings settings(QDir::currentPath() + "/config.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);  
 settings.sync();
 settings.beginGroup("Test");
 ValRead = settings.value("TestVal", 8).toInt();
 settings.endGroup();
```

I've tried without setting the Group, and just specifying the value of "Test\TestVal" but no luck.  Is there a way to see if the ini file is properly formatted?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that config.ini isn't in the same folder as your binary.

Comment: If you're running your app from Qt Creator and you're using the standard debug/release configuration in your build settings, Qt Creator will expect your ini file to be in your build directory, which will be a directory up from your binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you always get `8`, because you set this as default value here

```
 ValRead = settings.value("TestVal", 8).toInt();
```

And as said `MrEricSir` abd `Andrew Dolby` your file placed in wrong place. It means that `QSettings` can't search file and return default value and you always get this default value - `8` When you work in `Qt Creator` you should pay attention on this.

Place your `.ini` file in correct place and use this code. This checking will save you from errors in future.

```
if(QFile("correctPath").exists())
{
    QSettings settings("correctPath",QSettings::IniFormat);

    settings.sync();
    settings.beginGroup("Test");
    int vvv = settings.value("TestVal",8).toInt();
    settings.endGroup();
    qDebug() << vvv << "value";
}
else
    qDebug() << "not exist";
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a path problem!  The Qfile().exists helped to narrow it down!

Comment: In my case I had an group named as `general` and did not work, so I only changed from `general` to whatever and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I literally broken all my mind trying to find out the reason of the same issue.

"General" group name is not acceptable for some reason, seriously. Changed "General" to "GeneralSettings", everything became fine

Answer (score 0):

My file was placed on the correct location. But the group name General was causing the problem. Changed it to something else and it started working.